# DB2 Query for fetching records from first query, if first query fails, then fetch from 2nd query

Tags: sql, db2

I want to fetch records from the first query, if first query fails then I want records from second query. I am not understanding how to write sql query for this.

Query 1 :

Select emp_id, emp_name from empInfo where addr_code=3

Query 2 :

Select emp_id, emp_name from empInfo where addr_code=1

can anyone please help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'fails'? Do you mean that it fails with something like a deadlock or do you mean that it doesn't return any rows?

Comment: you are looking at procedure territory ... SQL by itself doesnt work like a traditional programming language, which is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward if you formulate your requirements using logical predicates:

```
Select 
  emp_id, emp_name 
from 
  empInfo 
where 
  addr_code=3
or
  (addr_code=1
  and
  not exists ( select 1 from empInfo where addr_code=3 ))
```